# Difficulty logging in with safari on iPad

Tags: bug

I've been viewing the physics stack for a year but recently I've been unable to log in using iPad Safari. I can on the same device using skyfire. Why?

Comment: Details on the exact process?

Comment: I log in with google. When I get to the log in page and I try to choose google as my method of logging in, nothing happens. It's as if the iPad doesn't recognize that there is a link there. However it works on skyfire, another browser on my iPad.

Comment: Do you have private browsing turned on in your settings?  This disables some functionality needed for OpenID to function http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1677